# Javascript code completion for user functions?

Tags: mirth

Title says it all: does the internal Mirth Javascript IDE support code-completion and documentation for *user* defined functions?  I clearly see that it does with the built-in ones.

I'm wondering if I need to annotate my functions in a particular way, or perhaps it's not even supported at this time (current v3.3).

Comment: What is the reason for that? You can drug user defined functions from the Reference tab by selecting "User Defined Functions" category.

Comment: I'm creating objects that map to specific segment and sequences.  Basically, it's an abstraction to the typical "msg['SEG']['SEG.x']['SEG.x.x']" scheme.  For example, I want my users to simply specify PID.PatientAccount which would map to PID.18.1.  However, it would be fantastic if, when they type "PID." a list of associated sequences would pop-up.

Comment: You may play with 
 `new Packages.com.mirth.connect.client.ui.reference.ReferenceListFactory.getInstance();`
to see if newly added references are actually there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Nick is not answering you in Mirth forum, I'm guessing that this feature is not implemented. I tried to mimic to make it close to what you are trying to achieve, so in my case it works in a following way:

1) In a code template library create a "*Compiled Code Block*":

```
var sMSH = {
    sendingFacility: function () {
        return msg['MSH']['MSH.4']['MSH.4.1'].toString();
    },
    dateTimeOfMessage: function () {
        return msg['MSH']['MSH.7']['MSH.7.1'].toString();
    },
    messageControlId: function () {
        return msg['MSH']['MSH.10']['MSH.10.1'].toString();
    }
};
```

2) Then create several "*Drag-an-Drop Code Block*" like this with the template name "MSH.messageControlId" (which will be visible in user's defined code list):

```
sMSH.messageControlId();
```

3) Make sure that context is visible to your channel.

4) Now, go the the channel's transformer editor and select Reference > User Defined Code. All drag'n'drop codes should be there and they work as expected.

This is not code-completion as you wanted but I guess it's pretty close and hides mapping complexity from the coders.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Like you said, not quite code completion but accomplishes what I'm trying to achieve.